# How can i create a new edge loop / vertices where i've joined two separate objects? Boolean gives me strange results

Tags: modifiers

[image: Wireframe]

Hello, I am very new to blender.
I would like to join the top part of my vase (the long bit) with the base, and bevel out the join so its not so sharp. (same with the handles.)

I've tried to use the Boolean modifier but it looks really strange and i'm not sure why. I know my shapes are wonky on purpose.
Ideally i'd like a new edge loop where they intersect so i can bevel it. What else can i try?

[image: without Boolean]

Joined objects without Boolean

[image: with Boolean]

Objects with Boolean (Union) and it's gone weird.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to correct the topology, or cut a in your bottom object, make a circle from this hole (right click > LoopTools > Circle) and extrude up your vertical tube?

Comment: @moonboots Yes I'll try and combine this method with Harry McKenzies method and see what happens, thank for your replies

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you for your answer, I'm currently trying to follow it to attach my jug handles to the long bit, after cutting a hole and extruding the long bit. I've selected my handle mesh and in edit mode, clicked "Intersect (Knife)" but it's telling me No Intersections found. Do i need to Join the jug object with the handle object?

Comment: yes first join them so they are part of same mesh. select the handle then shift select jar then press `ctrl+j`